# How to run tests programmatically in Nightwatch.js?

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm using [Nightwatch.js](http://nightwatchjs.org/) and trying to run E2E tests using the programmatic API as described [here](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#programmatic-api).

Here is my `nightwatch.json` file:

```
{
  "src_folders": ["tests"],

  "webdriver": {
    "start_process": true,
    "server_path": "node_modules/.bin/chromedriver",
    "port": 9515
  },

  "test_settings": {
    "default": {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and `index.js` script:

```
const Nightwatch = require('nightwatch');

Nightwatch.runTests(require('./nightwatch.json')).then(() => {
  console.log('All tests has been passed!');
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

When I run the script I get the error:

> Error: An error occurred while retrieving a new session: "Connection refused to 127.0.0.1:9515". If the Webdriver/Selenium service is managed by Nightwatch, check if "start_process" is set to "true".

I feel it needs some configuration but the [documentation](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#programmatic-api) isn't very helpful here.